# Trouble excluding specific folders in a duplicity backup

Tags: directory, duplicity

I am trying to backup my web root using duplicity and am having trouble excluding specific folders.

I want to back up `/var/www/` that has manny subfolders containg sites :
eg :

```
/var/www/site1.com, /var/www/site2.com
```

I want to exclude logs and cache folders that can be annywhere in each sites folder structure.

eg :

```
/var/www/site1.com/cache, /var/www/site1.com/logs
```

or :

```
/var/www/site2.com/app/cache, /var/www/site2.com/app/logs
```

Cache folders are allways called 'cache'
Log folders are allways called 'logs'

The command I am using (that does not work) is :

```
duplicity --include /var/www/ --exclude cache --exclude logs --exclude "**" / s3+http://domain.com/files/
```

And I get the following error :

```
Fatal Error: The file specification
    cache
cannot match any files in the base directory
    /
Useful file specifications begin with the base directory or some
pattern (such as '**') which matches the base directory.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally worked it out :

```
duplicity --exclude "**cache/**" --exclude "**logs/**" /var/www s3+http://domain.com/files/
```

Comment: why ** (double-asterisks)? Is `--exclude "*cache*"` different than -`-exclude "**cache/**"` ?

Comment: Seems like it, If I remember correctly it will exclude all cache and log folder on the system and not just in the current file path.

Comment: What's also important is the order: the first matching `--include` or `--exclude` be applied.

Comment: Single asterisks match any string of characters not containing "/", so you need double ** to reach nested folders. `--exclude /var/www/**cache` would also work. As Thom says, order is very important - nested excludes should come first, otherwise the parent `--include /var/www` would override them (if there is one).